# JQuery - CORS Error

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do an API call using JQuery. The call works perfectly fine if it is not triggered by the press of a submit button. The moment I trigger it on the submit event, I get an error saying:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=jquery_language:javascript&sort=starts. (Reason: CORS request failed).
>   Blockquote

Here's the code:

```
var mainForm = $("#mainForm");
mainForm.on("submit", function(){
    var gitHubSearch = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=jquery_language:javascript&sort=starts"

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.get(gitHubSearch)
    .success(function(r) {
          console.log(r.items.length);
          displayResults(r.items);
        })
    .fail(function(err) {
          console.log("Failed to query GitHub");
          resultList.text("The API Call has failed.");
        })
    .done(function() {
          console.log("API Call completed");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin is required**

This header must be included in all valid CORS responses; omitting the header will cause the CORS request to fail.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  // allows Cross-Origin Request
```